# PGSQL Subquery in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

What's wrong with my query? I'm getting error:

> "SYNTAX ERROR IN LINE 3 NEAR invoices.date"

```
SELECT contacts.id, contacts.org, products.name, products.keynumber as “Number of users”, invoices.date, contacts.company, contacts.person, contacts.street, contacts.city, contacts.state, contacts.zip, contacts.email
FROM public.contacts, public.products, public.invoices, public.solditems
WHERE contacts.id = invoices.contact AND invoices.date IN 
(SELECT MAX(date) FROM public.invoices, public.solditems, public.products 
WHERE invoices.id = solditems.invoiceid AND solditems.product = products.id AND products.name LIKE ‘CGate%’ GROUP BY contact)
ORDER BY products.name
```

My goal is to find contact and invoice/product information for the latest invoice for each contact.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @jarlh don't think that's the problem, used invoices.date in many other of my queries since date is a column in my table.

Comment: Is it possible to share table structure and insert statement @NelsonSwasono?

Comment: @NelsonSwasono, oops, I read PLSQL (as in Oracle.) You're correct, Postgresql doesn't have date as reserved.

Comment: Please explain what the query is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query and let me know your feed-back:

```
SELECT contacts.id, contacts.org, products.name, products.keynumber as "Number of users", invoices.date, contacts.company, contacts.person, contacts.street, contacts.city, contacts.state, contacts.zip, contacts.email
FROM public.contacts 
inner join
public.invoices on contacts.id = invoices.contact
inner join 
public.solditems on invoices.id = solditems.invoiceid 
inner join 
public.products on solditems.product = products.id 
where invoices.date IN 
(SELECT MAX(date) FROM public.invoices
 inner join  public.solditems on invoices.id = solditems.invoiceid
 inner join  public.products on solditems.product = products.id 
 where products.name LIKE ‘CGate%’ GROUP BY contact)
ORDER BY products.name
```

It would be much easier to solve the problem if you can provide sample data.